# Crop image background out?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, image-format, crop

I just started using **photoshop** today, and this is my first question in Graphic Design, so pardon me if this is a simple question. I have bee researching for about two hours now, on how to **crop** out the background of an image, and just have the image. I then want to use this image in my android app, which accepts **png format.**

So, I tried using the **magic wand** and I succesfully got rid of the background. At this point, it was just a picture ontop of a white canvas:

[image]

Now, I wanted to save **only** the blue balloon part as a **png**. I have looked all around the web for this answer, and one of the answers was to go to **file->Scripts** This is an issue because I don't have the **scripts** button in the file tab:

[image]

I am completely lost. I have been stuck on this for a few hours now, but i'm sure you professionals will know what to do in a few minutes.

Thanks so much,

Rich

Comment: Hey Rich, this doesn't look like Photoshop CS6, so I removed the tag. This actually looks closer to Photoshop 2 or 5 or 6. Unfortunately there's really not much help anyone can provide here, that's up to 23 years out of date. Also I'm not sure how this relates to my answer (that you linked me from). My answer has to do with exporting multiple layers from a PSD not saving a single one as a PNG. To answer your question though you'll want to go to `File -> Save As...` and select PNG, if that's not an option, upgrade Photoshop.

Comment: Use "save for web" or "save as" and select png. Or look at the "export" options too. Clearly you have these options, I can see them on your screenshot ;) When the "save as for web" or "export" or "save as" will open, make sure to check a box that says "preserve transparency" if there's any. Also, you seem to have a white background, and your history says you discarded (deleted) the layer mask; are you sure you still have transparency?

Comment: Layers Panel looks like circa CS6 or newer (with the search fields).  It may not be a legitimate version though, which may account for issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really look like you got rid of the white background, so first make sure that it truly is gone:

1. Use your magic wand to select the white area.
2. Then go to `Select` and `Inverse`
3. `Copy` and `Paste` into a new layer*.

Next, you need to save as a PNG or GIF with a transparent background:

4. Hide the layer with the image that has the white background. (Make sure there is a "checkerboard" around your balloon.)
5. Go to `File` and `Save for Web`.
6. Select either PNG or GIF.
7. Make sure that `Transparency` is checked (see image).
8. Click `Save`.

[image]

(*) NOTE: Try to refrain from deleting pixels- which is considered "destructive" editing. Always work with layers to "back-up" your work by making edits to duplicate layers instead of the original image. It will help you undo or add other styles, filters, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Try save as> PNG or Save as>GIF

Comment: And make sure to use "indexed transparency" or else you are just back to a balloon with a white background. This will work for GIF, or PNG8 (not PNG24).